# Use Functor in general tree

Tags: haskell, functor

I want to implement functor in my data type Tree

```
data Tree e =  Empty |Nodo e [Tree e] deriving Show
```

I have this

```
instance Functor (Tree) where
    fmap _ Empty = Empty
    fmap f (Nodo y (x)) = Nodo (f y) (fmap f x)
```

in this last line is where I have problems

Comment: `fmap f x` would work, if only we had `x :: Tree e`. Instead, we have `x :: [Tree e]` which is similar but not the same. From this, can you see how to adapt your code?

Answer (score 3):

The children is a list of children. You should perform a mapping, where you `fmap` each child, so:

```
instance Functor Tree where
    fmap _ Empty = Empty
    fmap f (Nodo y x) = Nodo (f y) (map (fmap f) x)
```

or we can work with a helper function:

```
instance Functor Tree where
    fmap f = go
        where go Empty = Empty
              go (Nodo y x) = Nodo (f y) (map go x)
```

Comment: Nice trick with the code bolding.